# VSCode natvis working on some variables but not others of the same template type

Tags: visual-studio-code, natvis

[image]

Working with the above std::vectors on Android's NDK. If I define the natvis for std::__ndk1::vector_base as follows

```
    <Type Name="std::__ndk1::__vector_base&lt;*&gt;">
        <DisplayString>{{size={__end_ - __begin_}}}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]" ExcludeView="simple">__end_ - __begin_</Item>
            <Item Name="[capacity]" ExcludeView="simple">__end_cap_.__value_ - __begin_</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
                <Size>__end_ - __begin_</Size>
                <ValuePointer>__begin_</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
```

I get the following

[image]

Why is the natvis definition working for `unsigned char` but not `unsigned long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be a bug in VSCode as there was a bug reported in Aug2020 (now closed) that seems to imply that there is an issue when using `unsigned long` in templates.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5253